# How to make an HTML element unclickable?

Tags: javascript, html, click

How to make the HTML element without clicking?

Each element is clicked by JavaScript. Clicking on the element gets the `alert(this.id)`. How do I make `parent2` not clickable, but the button inside allows you to click?

Of course I will have more `parent3`, `parent..4` with div inside and forms. Is there a simple way?

It will help if there is a way to click it all within the parent(childs). Parent2, parent3 ... not to click, but form inside Parent2..,3..to be clickable

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId;

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
  div[i].onclick = function(e) {
    clickedDivId = this.id;
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(this.id);
  };
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#parent2 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#parent3 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<div  id="parent3">
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world2!')">Click 
Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to be notified for clicks on `#parent2`... why are you setting an `onclick` on it? Why are you allowing the button to propagate the event, but you stop propagation on other handlers, if you don't want the button click to propagate? What is the problem you are trying to solve? (Without more context, this is exactly like that joke "doctor, doctor, it hurts me when I do this" - "then don't do it")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of attaching `on-click` event on div put it on button only and that event handler should implement alert and `stopPropagation` logic.

No need to attach any `onClick` event on `div`

You Code should be like

`HTML`

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <button id="myButton" type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(event)">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

`Javascript :`

```
function buttonClicked(event){
      console.log('lklklk', event)
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert('Hello world!')

  }
```

Comment: Parent and child must be clicked, parent2,3..... not be clicked, but button inside must be clicked

Answer (score 0):

Add id or something for the button and check if the event was originated from it using the e.target. Below is the snippet

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e){if(e.target.id == "button") {alert("button clicked")}})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would exclude `parent2` from you onclick event:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId;

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
  if(div[i].id != "parent2"){ //<-- Only if div is not parent2
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
      clickedDivId = this.id;
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert(this.id);
    };
  }
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#parent2 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Altough I think it would be better to solve this with a class:

```js
var clickables = document.getElementsByClassName("clickMe")
var divCount = clickables.length;
var clickedDivId;

console.log(clickables);

for(let i=0; i<clickables.length; i++){
  clickables[i].onclick = function(e) {
    clickedDivId = clickables[i].id;
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(clickables[i].id);
  };
}
```

```css
 #parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#parent2 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="clickMe"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <button class="clickMe" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course I will have more parent3, parent4.... with div inside and forms. Is there a simple way

Comment: So whats your question then? @aldin_abdagic

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `parent2 div` to not run any code, just `return` when the `clickedDivId == "parent2"`.

```js
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var disDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div.dis");
var divCount = allDivs.length;


for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
  allDivs[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(this.className == 'dis')
      return;
    alert(this.id);
  };
}
```

```css
#parent, #parent2, #parent3 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.dis{
  cursor:not-allowed
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent2" class="dis">
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<div  id="parent3" class="dis">
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world2!')">Click 
Me!</button>
</div>
```

If you have multiple `divs` then you can assign them a class and in the event handler check if that class is present for that clicked `div`

Comment: Of course I will have more parent3, parent4.... with div inside and forms. Is there a simple way

Comment: You can keep the id's in an array and check if the clicked id is present in that array

Comment: You can also assign classes to disabled divs.. Check updated code.

Comment: Check updated code. It may be clearer. I apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can add some CSS code to button like :

```
button { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
 }
```

with this code button get a level higher than parent box,
remember parent box must have `position:relative`