# How to make only elements which have ids clickable?

Tags: javascript, class, click

Each div is clickable (JavaScript).

How to make it such that only elements with an id are clickable, and elements with a class are not clickable?

Is there a replacement option:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName ("div");
```

With

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName ("div");
```

I tried but did not work

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {

  div[i].onclick = function(e) {

    clickedDivId = this.id;
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(this.id);

  };
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.parentclass {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.childclass {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="childclass"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check whether it has an ID?

Comment: You don't have any elements with classname `div`

Comment: Select the elements having an id: `document.querySelectorAll('[id]');`.

Comment: You could have easily copied and pasted the snippet from [your last question with this same code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56255818/215552), BTW...

Comment: For this question, what about if the element has both an id and a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution where clicks on elements with existent attribute `id` are treated. You can add `else` section to JS code to process all of other clicked `div`.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if (e.target.id) alert(this.id);
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.parentclass {
  width: 450px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.childclass {
  width: 430px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="childclass"></div>
</div>
```

And this is a short coded JS:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

[...div].forEach( (el) => {
    el.onclick = function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.target.id &&  alert(this.id);
        }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280742/why-change-the-color-inside-the-diva-does-not-work   Thank you for your reply. I can ask you to answer the following question in the link

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious substitution of `getElementsByTagName` with `document.querySelectorAll('div[id]')` to only select `div` elements that have an `id` attribute, I would suggest delegating this event and handling the `id` part in the listener. This way there's only a single handler function, and it will work with elements that may be added / modified in the DOM later on.

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'click', e => {
   const { id } = e.target;
     if( id ){
        console.log( id );
     }
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/85ob2vqg/

Or in ES5

```
document.body.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
   var  target = e.target;
     if( target.id ){
        console.log( target.id );
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select by class like this:

```js
const idSet = document.querySelectorAll('#a');
const classSet = document.querySelectorAll('.a');

const log = t => () => console.log(t);

idSet.forEach(element => element.onclick = log('id click'))
classSet.forEach(element => element.onclick = log('class click'))
```

```html
<button id="a">1</button>
<button class="a">2</button>
<button class="a">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of the elements with an id like this:

`document.querySelectorAll('[id]');`

Then you can use an event listener for your clicks.

```js
    const clickableIds = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
    clickableIds.forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener('click', () => {
          alert('Here is your element object: ' + element);
      });
    });
```

```css
    #parent {
      width: 450px;
      height: 170px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    #child {
      width: 430px;
      height: 70px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .parentclass {
      width: 450px;
      height: 170px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .childclass {
      width: 430px;
      height: 70px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: left;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="childclass"></div>
</div>
```